# Asterisk problem with call between two extensions

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

I know that this problem is very popular, but i can't find anything what could help me with solve this issue.
I created two accounts in PJSIP and successfully registered SIP phones for these accounts. Now I want to make a call from number 103 to number 102. Asterisk return me this notice:
[Jun  8 07:54:12] NOTICE[5229]: res_pjsip_session.c:3228 new_invite: Call from '103' (UDP:xxx.xx.x.xx:xxxxx) to extension '102' rejected because extension not found in context 'voicebot-in'.

This is my PJSIP conf.

```
[udp-transport]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0

[102]
type=endpoint
transport=udp-transport
context=voicebot-in
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
auth=102
aors=102

[102]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=102
username=102

[102]
type=aor
max_contacts=10

[103]
type=endpoint
transport=udp-transport
context=voicebot-in
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
auth=103
aors=103

[103]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=103
username=103

[103]
type=aor
max_contacts=10
```

and below extensions.conf

```
[voicebot-in]
exten => 103,1, Dial(PJSIP/102)
```

Answer (score -1):

Space before dial command made it be command " Dial" which is not same as "Dial" and not exists in asterisk.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I removed space and still this same notice.

Comment: Sorry, debug is offtopic on SO. Use dialplan show or other debug commands.

Comment: Please note, that you have extension 103 and no extension 102 at all.